# Paragraph wrap with list-style-position: inside

Tags: html, css, list, paragraph

I'm trying to layout some list with paragraphs inside list items. The list bullets are custom images and with paragraph that is wider than container width it wraps and sencond line begins below the list image which I don't want.

It needs to be like:

[image]

And what I get is this:

[image]

My layout is this:

```css
ul.steps {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: table;
  h4 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  li {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    list-style-position: outside;
    text-indent: 2em;
  }
  li:nth-child(1) {
    background: url(../images/count1.png) no-repeat 0 7px;
  }
  li:nth-child(2) {
    background: url(../images/count2.png) no-repeat 0 7px;
  }
  li:nth-child(3) {
    background: url(../images/count3.png) no-repeat 0 7px;
  }
  li:nth-child(4) {
    background: url(../images/count4.png) no-repeat 0 7px;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="steps">
  <li>
    <div>
      <h4>Зарегистрируйтесь и откройте счет</h4>
      <p>Вы также можете открыть учебный демо-счет, чтобы понять принципы торговли.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Установите программу или откройте веб-трейдер в браузере</h4>
    <p>Для работы на Forex необходима торговая платформа. Для вашего удобства мы предлагаем терминал Metatrader, который вы можете бесплатно установить с нашего сайта, и веб трейдер для онлайн торговли в браузере.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Выберите торговую стратегию</h4>
    <p>Спрогнозируйте, возрастет или снизится цена на выбранный вами актив, и на основе прогноза сделайте ставку на продажу или покупку.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Получайте прибыль</h4>
    <p>Средства, полученные от торговли, вы можете вывести любым удобным способом. Мы гарантируем быстрые операции с любыми суммами</p>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- /.steps -->
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31644035/483779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't indent the text.

Add `padding-left` to the `li` and the image can be in the background there.

```css
ul.steps {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: table;
}
h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
li {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  list-style-position: outside;
  padding-left: 2em;
  background: url(http://www.fillmurray.com/g/16/16) no-repeat 0 7px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="steps">
  <li>
    <h4>Зарегистрируйтесь и откройте счет</h4>
    <p>Вы также можете открыть учебный демо-счет, чтобы понять принципы торговли.</p>

  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Установите программу или откройте веб-трейдер в браузере</h4>
    <p>Для работы на Forex необходима торговая платформа. Для вашего удобства мы предлагаем терминал Metatrader, который вы можете бесплатно установить с нашего сайта, и веб трейдер для онлайн торговли в браузере.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Выберите торговую стратегию</h4>
    <p>Спрогнозируйте, возрастет или снизится цена на выбранный вами актив, и на основе прогноза сделайте ставку на продажу или покупку.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Получайте прибыль</h4>
    <p>Средства, полученные от торговли, вы можете вывести любым удобным способом. Мы гарантируем быстрые операции с любыми суммами</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```